# Zabbix not getting data for one filesystem

Tags: linux, monitoring, filesystems, centos6, zabbix

I have Zabbix monitoring disk space for several volumes on several servers. It works fine on all of them except for one of the volumes on one of the servers which always reports as 0. However, when I run

```
./zabbix_get -s localhost -p 10050 -k 'vfs.fs.size[/home, free]'
```

locally on the machine in question, it gives me the correct, non-zero size which matches the output of `df`.

How can I go about troubleshooting and correcting this problem?

Comment: What is in the agent log?  1.x or 2.x?  Active or passive check?

Comment: @chris: There's no mention of the vfs key in the log or any errors. Only startup messages (collectors, listeners, active checks). It's version 2.0.0. And the checks are active. Values are returned successfully for other volumes on this server.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the item config for this host? Also, what is the latest data/history for the item showing are there previous dates with values other than 0?

Comment: @bmurtagh: It's the same template as used by other similar servers which do not exhibit this problem. As I said in the original post, this volume on this server *always* shows 0 in the Zabbix data screen, but `zabbix_get` *always* reports a correct value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had set the data type for /home to float, but for other volumes I had set it to unsigned decimal. On the servers that were reporting 0, the free space was larger than other servers and the value overflowed the field.

Setting the field type to unsigned decimal to match the others corrected the problem.

Answer (score 0):

(Just wanted to add my contribute if someone else pops by)

Thanks to this question I discovered `zabbix_get`, that I installed with `yum install zabbix-get` through [Zabbix Repositories](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manual/installation/install_from_packages).

If you get no data from `zabbix_get -s 127.0.0.1 -k agent.version` (this is a simple key to check this utility), check the `Server=` option in `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf` and be sure it contains localhost:

```
Server=myserver.mycompany.com,127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because unusual filesystem `simfs`. I added its name to regular expression `@File systems for discovery` in Administration->General->Drop down "Regular expressions" and now it works.